# Using Enricher to update List of records

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We are working on a use case that uses a Enricher.  The input payload to the enricher is the Department Object which contains an Employee List. 
The enricher calls the stored proc to get the department name.  Now we need to update each row of Employee with this department name.

Is this possible to assign the dept name to each Employee using xml configuration?

```
public class Department {

        private String deptId;
        private List<Employee> emp = new ArrayList<Employee>();

}

public class Employee {

       private String EmpId;
       private String EmpName;
       private String EmpDeptName;
}




<int:enricher id="DeptEnricher"
                  input-channel="findDeptChannel"
                  output-channel="empChannel"
                  request-channel="deptEnrichChannel"
                  request-payload-expression="payload.deptId">

</int:enricher>

<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
            id="sp-get-dept"
            data-source="dataSource"
            request-channel="deptEnrichChannel"
            is-function="false"
            stored-procedure-name="PROC.XXX_GET_DEPT"
            ignore-column-meta-data="true"
            expect-single-result="true">

        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_DEPT_ID"  direction="IN" />
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="V_DEPT_NAME"  direction="OUT"/>

        <int-jdbc:parameter name="V_DEPT_ID" expression="payload" />
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that via only XML configuration.

The `<property>` setting is based on the SpEL `setValue()`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions-assignment

You can't there iterate over a nested list and perform set for each item. It's not Java 8 with its `forEach()`.

You can achieve that via custom SpEL function: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/spel.html#spel-functions

But that looks for me much easier to store the `EmpDeptName` in the header and apply for each employee in the subsequent `<transformer>`. But anyway via some Java code.